# Capistrano deploy to different path on same server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, capistrano3

I am trying to deploy my application using capistrano. But I want to deploy my application to multiple paths of the same server.For example If for the first run I want to deploy it to below path

```
set :deploy_to, '/home/a/some_path/
```

Once completed the first one it should run for the second path that will be

```
 set :deploy_to, '/home/b/some_path/
```

and so on. Any suggestions how can I achieve this? Right now my single path deployment path is working AOK.

Comment: have 2 files, run separate cap commands

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your config file:

```
set :deploy_to, ENV["DEPLOY_PATH"]
```

Then, to deploy, run the command setting the `DEPLOY_PATH` variable:

```
DEPLOY_PATH="my/path" cap production deploy
```

Comment: Is there any way to set up the path directly on the file rather than using the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Using capistrano 3.8.2, I monkeypatched lib/capistrano/dsl/paths.rb in my deploy.rb, but then I found that I needed more work to get git wrapper set up right when there where different deploy users.
The result is at: https://gist.github.com/mcr/49e8c7034658120013c1fe49da77c2ac

But, I'm leaving the essence of the content here:

```
module Capistrano
  module DSL
    module Paths
      def deploy_to
        dir = @host.properties.fetch(:deploy_to) || fetch(:deploy_to)
        puts "For #{@host.hostname} deploy_to: #{dir}"
        dir
      end
    end
  end
end
```

(You can take the puts out, and shorten it to a one-liner, but I found the extra debug useful)

One then does:

```
server "server.client1.example.com", user: "client1", roles: %w{app db web}, deploy_to: '/client1/app/foobar'
server "server.client2.example.com", user: "client2", roles: %w{app db web}, deploy_to: '/client2/app/foobar'
```

where server.client1.example.com and server.client2.example.com are CNAMEs or duplicate A/AAAA records for the same server.  This also isolates the question of where each client is to DNS.

Comment: While the above worked, it proved in the end to be inadequate, and I've forked capistrano (and capistrano-bundler) to try to solve the problem fully.