# Capistrano Multiple Deploy Stages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano3

I have a Rails app and I would like to use Capistrano to deploy two versions: `production` and `staging`.

On my deploy.rb file I have:
`set :stages, ['staging', 'production']`

Then how can I use two paths without overriding them?

`set :deploy_to, '/home/deploy/Sites/staging/myname'`

`set :deploy_to, '/home/deploy/Sites/production/myname'`

I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27637194/1498118) but I'd like to keep the command line clean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create two files under `config/deploy/*.rb`, `production.rb` and `staging.rb`, to the `production.rb` add `set :deploy_to, '/home/deploy/Sites/production/myname'`, to the `staging.rb` add `set :deploy_to, '/home/deploy/Sites/staging/myname'`

[`Don't be lazy and read the Capistrano documentation`](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/faq/how-can-i-access-stage-configuration-variables/)

Answer (score 0):

Any data from `config/deploy.rb` can be defined for specific environments in `config/deploy/*`

example of `config/deploy/production.rb`

```
set :stage, :production
set :rails_env, :production
set :branch, "master"
```

example of `config/deploy/staging.rb`

```
set :stage, :staging
set :rails_env, :staging
set :branch, "staging"
```

This works for me with two environments from different branchs. 
I hope you define the `:deploy_to` and `server url` specifically as well.